# How does VeeValidate 4 differ with regard to field binding?

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate

I have a custom component that I am rendering this way

```
<template>
    <label class="form-input-label" :class="{ 'is-error': errors.errors[fieldName] }">
        <small class="form-input-title d-block" :class="{ 'is-error': errors.length > 0 }">{{ fieldName }}</small>
        <Field :type="type" :name="fieldName"
          :rules="rules"
          class="form-input-field d-block"
          :value="modelValue"
        />
        <small v-if="errors.errors[fieldName]" class="form-input-error" :name="fieldName" v-html="errors.errors[fieldName]"></small>
    </label>
</template>
```

ModelValue is a propery of the component defined as follow

```
modelValue: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: false
}
```

I am using this component in several parent components to render form text fields in this way:

```
<input-component v-model="form.firstName" :fieldName="firstNameFieldName" :rules="`required|max:20`" :type="text" :errors="errors"/>
```

I am working on add field initialization by trying to acheive it as I was use to with VeeValidate3: by passing my model as `v-model="form.firstName"`

Unfortunately the field does not shows the field initial value.

Does someone knows how to fix this?

Thanks!